# Diabetes Type 2 and Carrot Sugar

Tags: diabetes, type-2-diabetes

If one has diabetes type 2 and wants to reduce sugars, is it healthy to eat carrots?

Do carrots effect diabetics?
Is there any list of fruit and vegetables which are good for diabetics?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about diet and nutrition are off topic here unless they're directly related to medical treatment.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, non-starchy vegetables (and fruit) contain less carbohydrates. As far as effect on blood glucose goes, you might be looking for something like the glycemic index: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycemic_index

Carrots (and many others foods) are listed with their glycemic index here: https://www.glycemicindex.com/, e. g. there are some 10 different entries for carrots alone, depending on how they are prepared.

Raw carrots: https://www.glycemicindex.com/foodSearch.php?num=2492&ak=detail

The site also lists some references where tests on this can be found.

As a comparison, sweet corn vs. carrots: Sweet corn has about three times the glycemic index of carrots, i. e. it has more glucose.

For some diets, e. g. low carb diet types, foods with low glycemic index are used.